# Hi I want to ask about google map flutter: how to find if the user is inside the polygon or not All solution I have tried is not working

Tags: firebase, flutter

Hi I am working on app in which i want to know if the user is inside the polygon or not. kinly help with the code.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **[google_maps_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_utils)** plugin to check the given location is inside the polygon or not. Also this plugin provides other use-full utils as well

Comment: I just want to know how to pass the current location to the polyutils.containslocationpoly().

Comment: Can you please paste the exact code that you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [maps_toolkit](https://pub.dev/packages/maps_toolkit) package's `PolygonUtil.containsLocation` method to do check if a particular point is in a polygon.

Here's a sample code:

```dart
LatLng point = LatLng(37.4221, 122.0841);
List<LatLng> polygonPoints = [LatLng(14.4, 12.0), LatLng(50.9, 70.56), LatLng(45.3, 130.0)];
bool geodesic = true;
PolygonUtil.containsLocation(point, polygonPoints, geodesic);
```

For the `geodesic` property above,

> The polygon is formed of great circle segments if geodesic is true,
> and of rhumb (loxodromic) segments otherwise.
>
> http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately it's not working I have passed the list of latlng and that point but It is giving me an error.

Comment: Okay. What error is it giving you?

Comment: Undefined name 'PolygonUtil'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Comment: You need to import the package, by adding it to your pubspec.yaml file and adding this line: `import 'package:maps_toolkit/maps_toolkit.dart';` to the top of your file.
Checkout the installation guide: https://pub.dev/packages/maps_toolkit/install

Comment: This package is actually conflicting with google_map_flatter package it some key words like LatLng

Comment: The argument type 'Position?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'LatLng'.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so I try to replicate the error?

Comment: You can use named imports to get past the conflicts.

Comment: My issue has been resolved thank you for the help guys.